# Adjust Text Field Size Based on current language iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Is it possible to dynamically set the size of a text field, button or other visual atributes based on the current user selected language?

Code sample would be great! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily adjust the size of a text field, for example depending on the text it contains.

```
NSString *localizedText; 
textField.text = localizedText;
[textField sizeToFit];
textField.text = @"";
```

You can generate `localizedText` dynamically with methods such as `stringFromDate` etc. or keep an `NSDictionary` with appropriate strings and the locales as keys.